# Two validators for the same control not working

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm trying to use two validators for the same control as shown in below code

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbEmail" placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control" required=""></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ValidationGroup="DRF" Display="Dynamic"
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ValidationGroup="DRF" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

But the problem is the second validator works but the first validator doesnot. I tried flipping them but same thing happens.

What I have to do to make both of them work at the same time ?
Can you help me in this?

Comment: Did you find the answer? i have facing the exact same problem right now!

Answer (score 0):

Add an ErrorMessage attribute to the regex validator like so:

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ValidationGroup="DRF" Display="Dynamic"
ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: No use. Actually I'm in no need of error message. I'm using css